# Embedding a pre-trained Keras model with different input dimensions

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have a Keras character-level embedding model that takes an input of shape `(num_items, 45)` and spits out a vector of shape `(num_items, 128)`.

I currently use it in a sequence classification model with an input shape of `(num_items, num_terms, 128)`, but this requires prepping the data ahead of time.

I'd like to be able to embed the model in the sequence classification model so that the input shape would be `(num_items, num_terms, 45)` and that would be run through the original character model to output a layer of size `(num_items, num_terms, 128)`.

Is there a way to do this in Keras, even though the character model can only classify one term at a time? Perhaps with some sort of lambda layer?

Appreciate any help you could provide!

Answer (score 1):

Do you need to train your classifier with the recursive model too? Because if not, you might be able to achieve this with a lambda layer using tf.map_fn:

```
inputs = keras.layers.Input(shape=(num_terms, num_items, 45))
processed = keras.layers.Lambda(lambda x: tf.map_fn(classifier, x))(inputs)
```

Note that the order of num_terms and num_items is swapped here because tf.map_fn loops over the first dimension.

Otherwise you might be able to write a custom RNN cell around your model and use an RNN? (I'm not sure how well this would work, I haven't tried it).

Comment: Thank you. `tf.map_fn` is exactly what I needed to accomplish this task.